# Why isn't wave winding a DC generator like shorting two voltage sources of different potentials?

Tags: dc-motor, winding

Say each conductor moving in a magnetic field produces EMF \$e\$.

In the below setup, the first parallel branch has 5 coils (5,9,4,8,3) and second branch has 4 coils (1,6,2,7.)

This means, at a particular instant in time:

- The induced EMF in the first branch is 5e.
- The induced EMF in the second branch is 4e.

Isn't this like shorting two different voltage sources?

It feels something is wrong in my interpretation of induced EMF.

My thinking:

Maybe one coil gets shorted by a commutator segment, then both branches will have an identical number of coils, but this doesn't happen all the time right? There will be some time period in a cycle when no coils are shorted and all coils are producing EMF.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The situation is comparable to connecting two voltage sources in parallel, but they are not ideal voltage sources and there is more going on that that.

First of all, each coil and each part of each coil experiences a different level of magnetic flux. The level of flux changes as the angular position of the rotor changes. Each part of each coil also has some resistance and inductance. The voltage that is generated in each segment of coil varies as the rotor turns.

The voltages across each path are forced to be equal by the parallel connection. However the two currents can vary, so the output current can be relatively constant as it is divided into two varying parts. So the voltages that might otherwise tend to be unequal can balance themselves without current reversing in one branch or all of the current flowing in one branch.

The net result is that two parallel current paths are somewhat like two voltage sources in parallel, but that works reasonably well. There are some design details that are added to larger motors to improve the operation, but large complex commutator motors are pretty much a thing of the past.